# How do you continue to cast video with Google Photos after 5 mins

Tags: chromecast

When you play a video in google photos and your casting it to chrome cast the screen will shut off stopping the cast. So I end up having to use Wakey to keep the screen on. But that just heats the device up, draining the battery. Any ideas how to set it to continue to cast after 5 mins

Answer (score 0):

If you have rooted device, you can use http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-screen-backlight-off-xda-exclusive-t3037380

Otherwise you can search for other app for streaming (I mean replacing Google Photos)